# Using audio interface with iPhone Camera App

Tags: iphone, ios, photos.app, video, recording

Goal: Record video using iPhone with my AU volt476P. (All 4 channels)

When I connect my interface and record through the camera app (using the Apple branded camera adapter) I only get audio from channels 1 & 2 of the interface.

Firmware is up to date.
I've tried turing off "record stereo sound" in the camera settings
I've tried this with 2 different AU volts476P's and had the same problem.

All channels of my Volt476P work with my mac (logic Pro X).

What can I do?